# Different Commands For Different Events in a ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, listbox, mvvm-light

I have the following ListBox :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CityList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock x:name="Name" Text="{Binding Name }" />
                <TextBlock x:name="Country" Text="{Binding  Country}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The following article explains very well how to implement SelectionChanged :

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="Results" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Events}" SelectedItem="{Binding Event}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding benchmark.name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding summary}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding WodSelectedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=Results}" PassEventArgsToCommand="False"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

But in this example the `Selection Changed` will be the same for every Textblocks in my example i would like that my two textblocks have two different commands.

How can i do so ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the event triggers inside the `DataTemplate`. That should let you have two different commands for tap on `Name` and `Country`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CityList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock x:name="Name" Text="{Binding Name }" >
                   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding NameSelectedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=CityList}" PassEventArgsToCommand="False"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock x:name="Country" Text="{Binding  Country}" >
                   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CountrySelectedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=CityList}" PassEventArgsToCommand="False"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```